# How to execute JS end-to-end tests against a Play Framework application

Tags: playframework-2.0, jasmine, protractor

We have an AngularJS application which uses a Play Framework application as backend. Now we would like to execute some end-to-end tests against this application. The application should be started in test mode so that we can use our test configuration. Is there any integration with Jasmine, Protractor or an other JS test framework?

Answer (score 0):

sWhen you do End-to-end test it doesn't matter what technology you are using for the back-end, what you testing is what the final user can see (the front-end), you don't need to integrate nothing, as long as you use angular you will be able to use protractor.

I'm assuming the test mode you are talking about, is a custom internal configuration that you are using in your app, one technique you can use, is to set a  Check-box in your entry point page (could be your login page), that will load your app in "testing mode" (you'll have to build that functionality in your app), and make sure protractor click in the check-box before it start the testings:

```
 element(by.id('your-checkbox-for-testin')).click().then(function(){
     //the rest of the code for your test
 });
```

This is not the best practice though, ideal scenario is when you have an stage for QA, different from Production.